# Find & replace between html tags using python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add one line to the set of HTML files.

I want to put it between the `</h1>` and `<p>` tags, so I'm trying to find regex that is able to catch everything between these tags (there may be new lines, spaces, or nothing) and then replace it with my previously prepared html_line

As far, I have this:

```
for i in filesToBeChanged:
    lines = codecs.open(i,'r','utf-8').readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.find('</h1>') != -1: #here I probably need some .replace() :)
            print line
```

Comment: Please include sample input and desired output and your actual attempts at the problem. The question to which yours was closed for duplicate is quite specific while yours can be interpreted in various ways, some of which won't be solved by the answers of that linked question.

Answer (score 2):

You had better use [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for html processing.

Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<h1>First header</h1>
<p>first paragraph</p>
<h1>Second header</h1>
<p>second paragraph</p>
<h3>Third header</h3>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
    if h1.find_next_sibling('p'):
        h1.insert_after('\nSome text')
print soup
```

output:

```
<h1>First header</h1>
Some text
<p>first paragraph</p>
<h1>Second header</h1>
Some text
<p>second paragraph</p>
<h3>Third header</h3>
```

Comment: And demonstration of such? Otherwise, this is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @dizballanze I'm trying to do this your way, but I got error when insterting string after h1: 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/xI5nF1/1) with `re.sub`:

```
(?s)<\/h1>(.*?)<p>
```

`(?s)` enables the singleline mode so that `.` matches a newline symbol.

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?s)<\/h1>(.*?)<p>')
test_str = u"I want to put it between the </h1> and\nand <p> tags,"
subst = u"</h1>\1\n<tag att=\"va\">NEW TEXT</tag>\n<p>"
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use lookaheads and lookback, this should work:

```
(?<=\<\/h1\>)[\S\s]*(?=\<p\>)
```

Comment: "there may be ... or nothing" the above won't match 'nothing'.

Comment: Did you retry after the . -> \S correction?

Comment: What is your definition of 'nothing'? `[\s\S]+` matches at least 1 character, so to me, 'nothing' (for example `</h1><p>`) won't match your re. Also, since when does python use `//` delimiters?

Comment: Bad habit, these delimiters. I had misunderstood your statement, sorry! This should match nothing.